# Is there a function that determins the minimum distance of the code

Tags: arrays, distance, hamming-distance, hamming-code

is there mathlabs functions that when given (n,k) of a generalized array code it is able to generate all non-zero code words using (n,k) then find the minimum distance of the code, and determine the error detection capability td and error correction capabilities tc separately of the  code